# How to "slice" a 2D array into a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array that looks like:
`test = np.zeros (7110, 514)`

I need to "unpack" the first 90 values (rows) into the first value of the second dimension, the second 90 values (rows) into the second value of the second dimension, etc, so that the desired output will have shape:

`desired_output = np.zeros(90, 79, 514)`

I have tried something like:

```
a = np.split(test, 90, axis=1)
test1 = np.reshape(a, (79,90, 514))
```

but it just dragged me down a rabbit whole... Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why don't you provide a toy example, say `(8,3)`, and the expected result?

Comment: The expected result with (8,3) would be (4,2,3). Basically I want to divide the 0th axis in equal columns, and preserve the second dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand the question, do you have 7110 rows of 514 elements each and want to "group" the 7110 rows into 90 x 79 rows?

Because then you could do something like this:

```
>>> np.array(range(24)).reshape((6, 4))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

These are 6 rows of 4 elements each.

```
>>> np.array(range(24)).reshape((6, 4)).reshape(3, 2, 4)
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

We keep the rows as they are, but instead of 6 rows, we get 3x2 rows.

So the code you would need is just:

```
desired_output = a.reshape(90, 79, 514)
```